# How to get location of a mouse click relative to a swing window

Tags: java, swing, position, mouse

Say I'm in a Java Swing JFrame. I click my mouse. I want to get the location of the mouse click **within the GUI**. In java, the line

```
int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation.x;
```

Seems to give the location of the mouse on the entire screen. How would I get it's location relative to the GUI?

Comment: Try using [`MouseEvent.getPoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint())

Comment: have to look at SwingUtilities, for determine the real mouse locations and relative to JFrame

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) methods you can do:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x=e.getX();
    int y=e.getY();
    System.out.println(x+","+y);//these co-ords are relative to the component
}
```

Simply add this to your `Component` by:

```
component.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }
});
```

**Reference:**

- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: AFAIK, **getX()/getY()** they both return an `int value`, so there never appears a reason to cast the value explicitly as you doing in your case :-), though +1 for the rest.

Comment: Yes, but what if you wanted to get the location of the mouse relative to the JFrame, without having to first click?

Comment: @CodyRichardson with the MouseMotionListener, same concept as in the example but with methods mouseMoved and mouseDragged

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [`Component.getMousePosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getMousePosition()).

> Returns the position of the mouse pointer in this `Component`'s coordinate space if the `Component` is directly under the mouse pointer, otherwise returns `null`. If the `Component` is not showing on the screen, this method returns null even if the mouse pointer is above the area where the `Component` would be displayed. If the `Component` is partially or fully obscured by other `Component`s or native windows, this method returns a non-`null` value only if the mouse pointer is located above the unobscured part of the `Component`.

```
final Point mousePos = component.getMousePosition();
if (mousePos != null) {
  final int mouseX = mousePos.x;
  final int mouseY = mousePos.y;
  ...
}
```

... or, if you use a `MouseListener`, you may see [my original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396066/how-to-get-location-of-a-mouse-click-relative-to-a-swing-window/12396091#comment16656443_12396066)...

> Try using [`MouseEvent.getPoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint()).

The above will return the mouse point relative to the component to which the listener was bound.

```
public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent evt) {
  final Point pos = evt.getPoint();
  final int x = pos.x;
  final int y = pos.y;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add `MouseListener` to GUI component whose top left pixel should be threated as [0,0] point, and get x and y from MouseEvent

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {// provides empty implementation of all
                                           // MouseListener`s methods, allowing us to
                                           // override only those which interests us
    @Override //I override only one method for presentation
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
    }
});
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

[MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) has methods getX() and getY() that return the position relative to the source component.

Comment: See also [*How to Write a Mouse Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).