# Mouse detection at many positions

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent

I am using Java with Swing and I want to detect mouse clicks at a number of locations (~200) in the view.

Should I use coordinates to ascertain where the click occurs (requiring searching through every location) or add multiple JPanels over each location and listen for mouse events for all of them?

Comment: Check this [How to get location of a mouse click relative to a swing window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396066/how-to-get-location-of-a-mouse-click-relative-to-a-swing-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a great number of points, you can use a [QuadTree datastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to efficiently search through all points with a two-dimensional area as the search key. Although QuadTrees are not in the standard Java API, there are several Java implementations that you can easily find on the Internet.