# How to get the location of a mouse click

Tags: java, click, mouseevent, mouse, mouselistener

I'm trying to create a program which has to find the x and y cords on the screen of the user's mouse click.
After the it finds it, the program will start to do a procces that based on the x and y location.
How can do it?

Comment: The `MouseEvent` has `getX()` and `getY()` methods .

Comment: refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396066/how-to-get-location-of-a-mouse-click-relative-to-a-swing-window