# Java mouseEvent Check where mouse is pressed on Jframe

Tags: java, events

So basically I want my program to tell me the coordinates of where the mouse was pressed on the Jframe is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: What results did a query in your favorite search engine provide?

Comment: Try this one: https://www.google.cz/search?client=opera&q=java+mouse+click+event&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Use MouseListener http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

And I think this question was answered in StackOwerflow

[How to get location of a mouse click relative to a swing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396066/how-to-get-location-of-a-mouse-click-relative-to-a-swing-window)